# I want to create a square in flutter and how can I make the user zoom in and out from the edges of this square?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I will create the frame myself in flutter or the user can create it, I want the person using the application to size it how do I do this?

I was able to put as many squares as the user wanted, but I could not make the size

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you-

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  double _height = 80.0;
  double _width = 80.0;
  var _color = Colors.blue;
  bool _resized = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedSize(
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              vsync: this,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_resized) {
                      _resized = false;
                      _color = Colors.blue;
                      _height = 80.0;
                      _width = 80.0;
                    } else {
                      _resized = true;
                      _color = Colors.blue;
                      _height = 320.0;
                      _width = 320.0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: _width,
                  height: _height,
                  color: _color,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.